# SSL off for a specific URL Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, django, gunicorn

This configuration was working before, and now it is not.

I should mention this is Django, Gunicorn, and Nginx.

We are trying to make `https://toontowninfinite.com/rpc/` use http and not https (SSL) and the rest of the site still uses SSL.

This is the config:

```
server {
            listen 80;
            # Force HTTPS!
            server_name toontowninfinite.com;

            # Well, excluding the RPC server. (thanks chan!)
            location /rpc/ {
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_pass http://toontowninfinite;
            }
            location / {
                    rewrite ^  https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
                    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            }
    }
```

I do not see anything wrong here, any suggestions as to why it is forcing SSL still?

Comment: Permanent redirects are supposed to be cached by your browser, which will make changes difficult to pick up. Did you stop your web browser/clear your cache/use an anonymous window?

Comment: Show config for https part. Does it use strict-transport-security header?

Comment: In addition to my earlier remark about cached headers: your domain is behind the CloudFlare CDN, which also [caches HTTP headers](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168326-Are-301-and-302-redirects-cached-by-CloudFlare-) or a redirect to SSL might be [configured there](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-) as well

Comment: There currently is no page rules set at Cloudflare, i also purged everything over at cloudflare, and also clear my browser cache, and it still misbehaves. I do not hae "strict-transport-security" header in my SSL portion either. Is that needed?

Answer (score 0):

Because the directives after your `location /rpc/` continue to be interpreted.

You will find the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5238430/248390) helful to your case.

I suggest you to try with:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        # Force HTTPS!
        server_name toontowninfinite.com;

        # Well, excluding the RPC server. (thanks chan!)
        location ^~ /rpc/ {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://toontowninfinite;
        }
        location / {
                rewrite ^  https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }
}
```

Comment: That did not work i added the ^~ before it and restarted nginx, and it still does not behave properly.